# OpenGraph meta for facebook, linkedin and twitter

Tags: facebook, twitter, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm trying to make sure that when my website is shared the correct meta information is displayed. I thought I had it working but I'm experiencing a few issues on different social websites, as follows:

- Twitter pulls in the text but doesn't display the specified image.
- LinkedIn displays text but seems to use the wrong image so it's stretched.
- Facebook doesn't display anything. If I post the URL, that's all that's displayed as a hyperlink.

Originally I just had the `meta name="twitter:` stuff but have since added the `meta property="og:` above it as I was told that was needed for LinkedIn.

This is the meta/OpenGraph data I'm using in my website `head`:

```
<!-- OpenGraph -->
<meta property="og:title" content="myurl.com - What this website is" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Specialising in lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://myurl.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="/img/site/linkedin-media-image.png" />

<!-- Twitter -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@twitteruser">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://myurl.com">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="I am a lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod.">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Specialising in lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod.">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="/img/site/social-logo.png">
```

Can anyone spot what I'm missing? Twitter *seems* ok, aside from the image not display and the URL is correct. While LinkedIn doesn't use the `og` correctly and Facebook is non-existent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image requires a full path, I tried relative as well but didn't work.

Your use of "twitter:url", "twitter:title", twitter:description" and  "twitter:image" is redundant unless you want different behavior for twitter only. If these tags are not found, twitter will fall back to OGP tags.

For Facebook, you might be missing the following :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

Tools to debug OG preview :

- [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)
- [Twitter](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator)
- [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)

My problem is, LinkedIn seems to stretch the image in spite of their [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) saying that minimum size is 80 x 150px to prevent it from being artificially stretched to fit the layout.

Comment: Yeah I think I've got it working on _most_ platforms now. I copied the Twitter info from somewhere else but understand it falls back to the OGP tags if it's not there. I think it's quite usefully to though as they use different image aspect ratios. LinkedIn is a funny one. I actually put a support ticket in. Got everything as it should be and it still ignored the image I'd specified. It displayed the first thumbnail on the page instead. They acknowledged this was a problem at their end but no estimates on when it'll be resolved.

Comment: I am missing that Facebook link though, what's that for? Facebook does seem to work now but occasionally/intermittently it doesn't display the thumb/info. I wonder if that line will help. Originally I thought it was caused by not putting a space at the end of the URL, which is a bit strange!

Comment: their documentation says to include the namespace, which is what that line does.

Comment: Ah ok, that's handy and sheds a bit of light on why that happens then and at least there's a fix/workaround. So I just add that line in the head on every page. Does it matter where?

Comment: You don't need these tags and the namespace to be specified on every page. Just put it in the index.html.

Comment: That's handy. I assume it wouldn't do any harm to add it to every page, just out of curiosity? I actually got a message from LinkedIn on Saturday saying: _"The technical team informed me that the OG image is rejected because of having a high compression ratio. Please change the resolution to <200 and try once."_ Which might explain why the wrong image is used. Strange issue though.

Comment: Taking a look at the image it's only 9KB and a black/white PNG so I'm surprised that's a problem.

Comment: Through what channel did you communicate with them ? May be I can chime in. I tried with a resolution of <200 as well ... it didn't work.

Comment: It was through the LinkedIn support centre. Not sure if it's only accessible by myself or an option forum. I'll check.

Comment: for Linkedin: https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the full path of the image. Also with facebook you may need to scrape the page again.

If you go to this page https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ enter your site it should show you any errors. You will also need to hit the scrape again button when you make any changes

Comment: Thanks, one of the warnings I get is _"The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."_ so I guess that's referring to the path as `og:image` is there. Mind, it does say _"The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id"_ as well, any some of those tags are included?